# What are "angles" in dimension $>2$ really called?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, geometry, terminology, linear-groups

I was pondering angles in spaces of dimension greater than $2$, and ended up coming up with the following:

> **Definition 0.** Let $V$ denote a real vector space. Then a *ray* in $V$ is a subset $\alpha$ of $V$ such that for all $x,y \in \alpha$, there exists unique $a \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $ax = y$.
>
> **Definition 1.** Let $V$ denote a real vector space equipped with a norm and an orientation. Then an *angle* in $V$ is a bijective orientation preserving isometry $V \rightarrow V$, and the angle from a ray $\alpha$ to a ray $\beta$ is defined as the unique angle $\theta$ such that firstly, $\theta(\alpha) = \beta$, and secondly $\theta$ stabilizes the orthogonal complement of $\mathrm{span}\{\alpha,\beta\}$.

Note that if $V$ is two-dimensional, we can get a bijective correspondence between angles and rays by choosing a ray to be the "identity angle", and these can in turn be put into bijective correspondence with the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/2\pi\mathbb{Z}$. Anyway, I'm just wondering what "angles" in the sense that I use the word above are really called, and how best to refer to the "angle between" two rays.

Comment: Aren't these just "rotations"?

Comment: @OscarCunningham, I think you're right. I guess we could call them "linear rotations" to emphasize that they're rotations about the origin. Also, it occurs to me that we don't need $V$ to be oriented; simply assuming that the determinant of $f$ equals $1$ should do the trick.

Comment: On second thoughts, I think in $n$ dimensions people use the word "rotation" for determinant $1$ isometries fixing a $n-2$ dimensional "axis", and for $n>3$ this is a strict subset of all the determinant $1$ isometries. So you should pick whether you want to talk about just the "rotations" or all of $SO(V)$.

Answer (score 1):

This definition means that the nonnegative reals don't form a ray, and the bisector of an angle $CAB$ doesn't contain $A$.

That's OK, I guess, but the real problem is that the set of positive rationals forms a ray, and that just seems weird.

When you say "stabilizes", do you mean pointwise or setwise? For "setwise", in 4-space you can send $x$ to $y$ and $y$ to $-x$, but send $z \to -z, w \to -w$, and still stabilize the $zw$-plane, but without fixing it. That kinda kills "uniqueness", since sending $z\to z, w \to w$ also provides an "angle." If you mean pointwise, then your definition can be turned into something equivalent:

Pick a basis $u_1, \ldots, u_{n-2}$ for the orthogonal complement, and extend it to an oriented basis for $n$-space by adding in the vector $x$ and the vector $z$. Then the rotation you've described splits as a sum of an $n-2$ dimensional identity and a 2-dimensional rotation in $xz$ coordinates. And then the "angle" is just the ordinary $2D$ angle measure. I guess I'm saying that once you realize that all the action is happening in a 2-plane, the complementary $n-2$ plane is just kind of a red herring.

What I like about your definition is that it emphasizes transformation.

What I don't like is that one of the useful things about angles is angle *measure*, and it's a little tricky to get that angle measure from the transformation.

To answer your last question: the angle between two rays is usually called "the angle between two rays", where a ray consists of all nonnegative multiples of some nonzero vector, and where the angle is measured by taking nonzero vectors $u$ and $v$ in each ray and defining 
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{u \cdot v}{\|u\|\|v\|}\right).
$$

Comment: Yes, the orthogonal complement is meant to be stabilized pointwise; I guess what I really should have said is that each element of the orthogonal complement is required to be a fixed point of $\theta$. I also like your point about how my definition of 'ray' is broken - should have thought about it more carefully.